# Writing a stochastic process in a canonical way WLOG

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, stochastic-processes

Let $(X_t)_{t\geq 1}$ be a real stochastic process on a probability spae $(\Omega,\mathcal F,P)$. In my book it is written that we may assume WLOG  that $(X_t)$ is the canonical process
on the probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal F,P)=(\mathbb R^\mathbb N,\mathcal B(\mathbb R)^\mathbb N,P)$.

If we define the map $Y$ associating to every $\omega\in\Omega$ the map $t\mapsto X_t(\omega)$, then $Y$ is $\mathcal F-\mathcal B(\mathbb R)^\mathbb N$ measurable, and its distribution $P_Y$ is a probability measure on $(\mathbb R^\mathbb N,\mathcal B(\mathbb R)^\mathbb N)$. If we define the real process $(p_t)_{t\geq 1}$ on $(\mathbb R^\mathbb N,\mathcal B(\mathbb R)^\mathbb N,P_Y)$ by $p_t((x_n))=x_t$, then $(p_t)$ has the same joint distribution as $(X_t)$.

Shouldn't we have $(\mathbb R^\mathbb N,\mathcal B(\mathbb R)^\mathbb N,P_Y)$ instead of $(\mathbb R^\mathbb N,\mathcal B(\mathbb R)^\mathbb N,P)$?

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: As usual, if the process exists $X:\Omega\times T\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ exists, where $(\Omega,\mathscr{F},\mathbb{P})$ is some probability space, then the $P$ in the canonical space $(\mathbb{R}^T,\mathscr{B}(\mathbb{R}^{\otimes T},P)$ refers to its law, i.e. $P=\mathbb{P}\circ X^{-1}$

Comment: @OliverDiaz Thank you I was unaware of this convention.  So the canonical process is another process on a different probability space but with the same distribution as the original one?

Comment: @That is right! This is reminiscent to using $((0,1),\mathscr{B}(0,1),\lambda)$ as a canonical probability space. There for example, you can generate i.i.d Bernoulli sequences by considering $x_n(\omega)$ to be the $n$-th bit in the binary expansion of $\omega$. You can also take the product $\{0,1\}^\mathbb{N}$ with the product $\sigma$-algebra and show that there is a measure $P$ such that $P(\pi_1(\omega)=\varepsilon_1,\dots,\pi_{j_m}=\varepsilon_m)=2^{-m}$ for all $m\in\mathbb{N}$ and $\varepsilon_j\in\{0,1\}$, where $\pi_j$ is the protection onto the $j$-th component.